# Apex Code to retrieve value like vlookup but in Salesforce?

Tags: for-loop, triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

So I have two custom objects:  The Workload_Unit_Score__c object is a mapping table, with a reference field (WLU_Combination_Value__c) and a value (Score__c) for each row reference.  We receive requests each day to process contractual agreements.  A new record is created on the Agreement_Title__c object for each request.  Each record is assigned a Workload_Unit_Score__c, based on its WLU_Combination_Value__c.

I basically want to do something similar to an excel vlookup  - each time we receive a request and a new Agreement_Title__c record is created, I want a trigger to take the WLU_Combination_Value__c, retreive a Score__c from the Workload_Unit_Score__c object, and populate that value in the Workload_Unit_Score__c field.  The two custom objects are not related.  Below is a summary of the fields.

-Workload_Unit_Score__c object(sort out like a "definition" or
   "reference"    table)

- Name
- MiscField1
- MiscField2
- MiscField3
- WLU_Combination_Value__c (a formula field that concatenates MiscField1 + MiscField2 + MiscField3)
- Score__c (a score designated for each unique WLU_Combination_Value__c)

-Agreement_Title__c object(contractual agreements)

- Name
- MiscField1
- MiscField2
- MiscField3
- WLU_Combination_Value__c (a formula field that concatenates MiscField1 + MiscField2 + MiscField3)
- Workload_Unit_Score__c (a score given to each unique WLU_Combination_Value__c)

I have run the code below but I get "Compile Error: expecting right curly bracket, found '' at line 22 column 0"  But I think there may be other issues with the code that wont work.

Can someone assist?  Is there an easier way to do this?

```
trigger updateWLUvalue on Agreement_Title__c (before insert) {

    Map<String,Agreement_Title__c[]> relatedScores = new Map<String, Agreement_Title__c[]>();

    for (Agreement_Title__c agmtt : trigger.new) {
        if(!relatedScores.containsKey(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c)){

            relatedScores.put(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c, new Agreement_Title__c[]{});
    }

    relatedScores.get(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__C).add(agmtt);

    for(Workload_Unit_Score__c wus : [Select Id, Score__c, WLU_Combination_Value__c 
                                          FROM Workload_Unit_Score__c 
                                          WHERE WLU_Combination_Value__c 
                                          IN : relatedScores.keySet()]){
        for(Agreement_Title__c agmtt2 : relatedScores.get(wus.WLU_Combination_Value__c)){
            agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wus.Score__c;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is the missing close-curlybracket at the end. Your first IF-statement didn't close. 
Patched code:

```
trigger updateWLUvalue on Agreement_Title__c (before insert) {

    Map<String,Agreement_Title__c[]> relatedScores = new Map<String, Agreement_Title__c[]>();

    for (Agreement_Title__c agmtt : trigger.new) {
        if(!relatedScores.containsKey(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c)) {

            relatedScores.put(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__c, new Agreement_Title__c[]{});
        }
    }

    relatedScores.get(agmtt.WLU_Combination_Value__C).add(agmtt);

    for(Workload_Unit_Score__c wus : [Select Id, Score__c, WLU_Combination_Value__c 
                                          FROM Workload_Unit_Score__c 
                                          WHERE WLU_Combination_Value__c 
                                          IN : relatedScores.keySet()])
    {
        for(Agreement_Title__c agmtt2 : relatedScores.get(wus.WLU_Combination_Value__c)) {
            agmtt.Workload_Unit_Score__c = wus.Score__c;
        }
    }
}
```